# How to link in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im a new to codeigniter and have seen a tutorial for theme integration, but it didnt tackle how to properly link the links in the nav_bar, i have been doing some self studying and learned that every button on the nav_bar should be a controller and the href should be with a `<?php base url('')?>`, please see the codes below,

*nav_bar.php* located in views folder

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('aboutus')?>">About Us</a>`

*aboutus.php* located in controller folder

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Aboutus extends CI_Controller { 

    public function index()
    {    
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('nav_bar');           
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Where did i go wrong? and how do i fix it?
Thank you...

Comment: You may need to set routes http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: And have you set your base_url.

Comment: Do you getting page not fund error?

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did You remove **index.php** on your **htaccess**?
if not below url will works for you

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/aboutus">About Us</a>
```

Comment: No Problem :) @beldion

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to loaded the **URL Helper Class** in your controller or in `autoload.php` because to use base_url() (shorthand) you need to load url helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

**Some Examples:**

If you want to use this URL:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>aboutus
```

than, you need to modify your `.htaccess` file as:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you are looking for this this URL:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/aboutus
```

than, no need to change in `.htaccess` file.

Or if you are looking for this this URL:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>about-us
```

than, you need to add this route in your `config/routes.php` file:

```
$route['about-us'] = "aboutus";
```

---

**[From the CodeIgniter 3](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html):**

You can also use site_url() for getting your required result as:

```
echo site_url('aboutus');
```

**The above example would return something like:**

```
http://domain.com/index.php/aboutus
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code
in codeigniter anchor() function is available for create a link
       **syntax**
anchor("controller_class_name/function_name","link_name");

```
<?php
 echo anchor("welcome/add_user","ADD USER");
?>
```

Comment: if this code do not work than please download new setup of codeigniter because in past i face this error and solve by create new codeigniter setup other wise try this code above creatting link $this->load->helper('url');

Answer (score -1):

check the routing and use

```
<a href='<?= base_url("aboutus")?>'>About Us</a>
```

Comment: By the way <?= is not preferable mostly.

Comment: i think from php5 there can be used

Comment: i mean can be used  :D

Comment: yes, the base url has already been set... thank you very much for your answers... :)